# Snakemake Error with MissingOutputException

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to run STAR with snakemake in a server,
My smk file is that one :

```
import pandas as pd

configfile: 'config.yaml'

#Read sample to batch dataframe mapping batch to sample (here with zip)
sample_to_batch = pd.read_csv("/mnt/DataArray1/users/zisis/STAR_mapping/snakemake_STAR_index/all_samples_test.csv", sep = '\t')

#rule spcifying output
rule all_STAR:
    input:
        #expand("{sample}/Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam", sample = sample_to_batch['sample'])
        expand(config['path_to_output']+"{sample}/Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam", sample = sample_to_batch['sample'])

rule STAR_align:
    #specify input fastq files
    input:
        fq1 = config['path_to_output']+"{sample}_1.fastq.gz",
        fq2 = config['path_to_output']+"{sample}_2.fastq.gz"
    params:
        #location of indexed genome andl location to save the ouput
        genome = directory(config['path_to_reference']+config['ref_assembly']+".STAR_index"),
        prefix_outdir = directory(config['path_to_output']+"{sample}/")
    threads: 12
    output:
        config['path_to_output']+"{sample}/Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam"
    log:
        config['path_to_output']+"logs/{sample}.log"
    message:
        "--- Mapping STAR---"
    shell:
        """
        STAR --runThreadN {threads} \
        --readFilesCommand zcat \
        --readFilesIn {input} \
        --genomeDir {params.genome} \
        --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate \
        --outSAMunmapped Within \
        --outSAMattributes Standard
        """
```

While STAR starts normally at the end i have this error:

```
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 14 of /mnt/DataArray1/users/zisis/STAR_mapping/snakemake/STAR_snakefile_align.smk:
Job Missing files after 5 seconds:
/mnt/DataArray1/users/zisis/STAR_mapping/snakemake/001_T1/Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Job id: 1 completed successfully, but some output files are missing. 1
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

I tried --latency-wait but is not working.
In order to execute snake make i run the command

```
users/zisis/STAR_mapping/snakemake_STAR_index$ snakemake --snakefile STAR_new_snakefile.smk --cores all --printshellcmds
```

Technically i am in my directory with full access and permissions
Do you think that this is happening due to strange rights in the execution of snakemake or when it tries to create directories ?
It creates the directory and the files but i can see that there is a files `Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bamAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam .`

IS this the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your STAR command does not have the option that says which file and directory to write to, presumably it is writing the default filename to the current directory. Try something like:

```
rule STAR_align:
    input: ...
    output: ...
    ...
    shell:
        r"""
        outprefix=`dirname {output}`

        STAR --outFileNamePrefix $outprefix \
            --runThreadN {threads} \
            etc...
        """
```

> I am runing the command from my directory in which i am sudo user

I don't think that is the problem but it is strongly recommended to work as regular user and use sudo only in special circumstances (e.g. installing system-wide programs but if you use conda you shouldn't need that).

Comment: outprefix=`dirname {output}` should be written in rule STAR_align or in  rule all_STAR or in shell ??

Comment: In the `shell` string of rule STAR_aling - see edited answer. You probably need to adjust it though - this is just an idea that hopefully puts you in the right direction

Comment: i will try it ! for now i tried to run STAR in command line and it worked !!! STAR         --runThreadN 60 --readFilesCommand zcat --readFilesIn 001_T2_1.fastq.gz 001_T2_2.fastq.gz        --genomeDir /mnt/DataArray1/users/zisis/STAR_mapping/snakemake_STAR_index/Homo_sapiens.GRCh37.STAR_index         --outSAMtype BAM Unsorted         --outSAMunmapped Within         --outSAMattributes Standard --outFileNamePrefix /mnt/DataArray1/users/zisis/STAR_mapping/001_T2

Comment: with snakemake i still get the following error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 561, in snakemake
    success = workflow.execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 850, in execute
    success = scheduler.schedule()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/snakemake/jobs.py", line 675, in prepare
    f.prepare()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/STAR_mapping'`

Comment: `Permission denied: '/STAR_mapping'` suggests you are trying to write to root directory and this is probably not what you want. Edit your question with more details of the snakefile and how you execute it. For debugging consider also running snakemake with options `-p -n` to print the shell commands without executing them.

Comment: Into my direcotry i execute `/zisis/STAR_mapping/snakemake_STAR_index$ snakemake --snakefile STAR_new_snakefile.smk --cores all --printshellcmds`

Comment: it should be OK to write to /STAR_mapping directory and the permissions are drwxrwxrwx but there is nothing about root.so how can i change it and make it work in this directory ??